# How to Skip updating if a field is not empty in woocomerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use wp all import to synch my woocommerce with ebay, end i wrote this function to add a single sku on every variation

```
function set_value_for_all_vars($id) {
    $prod = wc_get_product( $id );
    if ( get_class( $prod ) == 'WC_Product_Variable' ) {    
        $value = get_post_meta( $id, '_ebay_ean', true );
        $count=0;
        foreach ( $prod->get_available_variations() as $var ) {
            $count++;
            update_post_meta( $var['variation_id'], '_ebay_ean', $value );
            update_post_meta( $var['variation_id'], '_sku', $value . '-' . $var['variation_id'] . '-' . $count );
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is simply, when wp-all-import run an update this funcion change the variation sku, but i need that skus added in creation of variation must never change. Someone can suggest a change?

what i think is best way is a control that skip update if the sku for the variation is not empty.
Someone can suggest some modify?

Comment: i think this will work: if (empty(get_post_meta( $var['variation_id'], '_ebay_ean', $value ))) { update_post_meta( $var['variation_id'], '_ebay_ean', $value );
            update_post_meta( $var['variation_id'], '_sku', $value . '-' . $var['variation_id'] . '-' . $count );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MY solution:

simply a check to verify is "sku" is empty! So in case is empty it writes else...exit...is correct?

```
function set_value_for_all_vars($id) {
    $prod = wc_get_product( $id );
    if ( get_class( $prod ) == 'WC_Product_Variable' ) {    
        $value = get_post_meta( $id, '_ebay_ean', true );
        $ebay_price = get_post_meta( $id, '_ebay_start_price', true );
        $count=0;
        foreach ( $prod->get_available_variations() as $var ) {
            $count++;
            update_post_meta( $var['variation_id'], '_ebay_start_price', $ebay_price );
            $post_meta2 = get_post_meta($var['variation_id'], '_sku', true );
            if (empty($post_meta2)) {
            update_post_meta( $var['variation_id'], '_ebay_ean', $value );
            update_post_meta( $var['variation_id'], '_sku', $value . '-' . $var['variation_id'] . '-' . $count );
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function set_value_for_all_vars($id) {
   $prod = wc_get_product( $id );
   if ( get_class( $prod ) == 'WC_Product_Variable' ) {    
     $value = get_post_meta( $id, '_ebay_ean', true );
     $count=0;
     foreach ( $prod->get_available_variations() as $var ) {
        $count++;
        $ebay_product_sku = get_post_meta($var['variation_id'],'_ebay_ean',true);
        if(!$ebay_product_sku)
        {
           update_post_meta( $var['variation_id'], '_ebay_ean', $value );
        }
        $woo_product_sku = get_post_meta($var['variation_id'],'_sku',true);
        if(!$woo_product_sku)
        {
           update_post_meta( $var['variation_id'], '_sku', $value . '-' . $var['variation_id'] . '-' . $count );
        }
       }
     }
  }
```